# Template Specialization for basic POD only

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is there a subtle trick for template specialization so that I can apply one specialization to `basic POD` (when I say basic POD I don't particularly want struct POD (but I will take that)).

```
template<typename T>
struct DoStuff
{
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Generic\n";}
};
template<>
struct DoStuff</*SOme Magic*/>
{
    void operator()() { std::cout << "POD Type\n";}
};
```

Or do I have to write specializations for each of the built in types?

```
template<typename T>
struct DoStuff
{
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Generic\n";}
};


// Repeat the following template for each of
// unsigned long long, unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned char
//          long long,          long,          int,          short, signed   char
// long double, double, float, bool
// Did I forget anything?
//
// Is char covered by unsigned/signed char or do I need a specialization for that?
template<>  
struct DoStuff<int>
{
    void operator()() { std::cout << "POD Type\n";}
};
```

Unit Test.

```
int main()
{
    DoStuff<int>           intStuff;
    intStuff();            // Print POD Type


    DoStuff<std::string>   strStuff;
    strStuff();            // Print Generic
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm curious - What kind if "stuff" do you want to do that the implementation doesn't already do differently for POD types?

Comment: I am using boost::mpl. For class like objects I need to register an action that manipulates the class object (and register actions for all its members). For normal POD objects I have a much simpler action that will be registered to perform the action on the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want only fundamental types and not user-defined POD types then the following should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_fundamental.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

template<typename T>
struct non_void_fundamental : boost::integral_constant<
    bool,
    boost::is_fundamental<T>::value && !boost::is_same<T, void>::value
>
{ };

template<typename T, bool Enable = non_void_fundamental<T>::value>
struct DoStuff
{
    void operator ()() { std::cout << "Generic\n"; } const
};

template<>
struct DoStuff<T, true>
{
    void operator ()() { std::cout << "POD Type\n"; } const
};
```

If you also want user-defined POD types, then use `boost::is_pod<>` instead of `non_void_fundamental<>` (and if you're using C++11 and doing this for optimization purposes, use `std::is_trivially_copyable<>` instead).

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, many traits have been added to the standard library, and most seem particularly aimed toward interesting specializations (and notably bitwise manipulations).

The top-level trait you could be interested in is [`std::is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial), however there are many others:

- `std::is_trivially_default_constructible`
- `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible`
- `std::is_trivially_move_constructible`
- `std::is_trivially_copyable` (can be copied via `memcpy`)

In general, the Standard has tried to get as finer grained traits as possible so you need not rely on such broad assumptions as `is_pod` but instead fine-tune your constraints to match what your methods really need.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has [`boost::is_pod`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html).  Is that what you're looking for?

(I've never used it, so I won't embarrass myself by trying to formulate the precise code that you require for your example.)