# Type conflict in template operator overload

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm sorry this sounds like a common question, I couldn't find the answer to my problem as far as I looked. The closest post would be this one: [Template Specialization for basic POD only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863965/template-specialization-for-basic-pod-only)

Let's say I have a class `template <class T> class A {...};`, and I want to overload operator+ as an internal binary operator (two objects of type A), and as a mixed binary operator (object of type A and numeric POD type).

Ideally, what I would like to write is:

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

// Declare/fine template
template <class T> class A {...};

// Internal binary operator
template < class T, class U >
    A< typename common_type<T,U>::type >
operator+ ( const A<T> &a, const A<U> &a ) { ... }

// Mixed binary operator
template < class T, class U >
    A< typename common_type<T,U>::type >
operator+ ( const A<T> &a, const U &b ) { ... }
```

But then it seems like the second definition is in conflict with the first one. Using the second definition, I know how to make sure U is a numeric POD type, that's not the point. If I go that way, the problem is that I have no way of knowing what underlying template type is enclosed in U if it is some A.

Please tell me if my question is not clear enough, and thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: The template specification got wiped out by the HTML filter, in my last sentence "U if it is some `A<T>`". In short, I'm saying T is hidden.

Comment: `template < class T, class U, typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<A<T>, U>::value, void>::type >
    A< typename common_type<T,U>::type >
operator+ ( const A<T> &a, const U &b );` should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by "underlying template type enclosed in U"? The mixed operator wouldn't be choose if U is `A<SomeType>` because the internal is a better match. Do you want to treat the case `A< A<U> >` in the internal operator?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. pmr, you are right, the problem actually happens before, because of common_type. Since there is no common type between 'A<T>' and U, we abort before the best match can be assessed. Morwenn, your solution looks like something I tried, but is incorrect in this context; U could be 'A<S>' with S != T, and I should still be able to perform the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work with a little helper trait to distinguish specializations of `A` from more general types:

```
#include <type_traits>


// "A" template    

template <typename> class A {};


// Traits for "A-ness":

template <typename> struct is_a : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct is_a<A<T>> : std::true_type { };


// Operators:

template <class T, class U>
A<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>
operator+(const A<T> & a, const A<U> & b);

template <class T, class U,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<!is_a<U>::value>::type>
A<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>
operator+(const A<T> & a, const U & b);
```

This excludes the second overload from the viable set immediately, and so the problem of determining the return type of the second overload never comes up when only the first one is desired.

(This is an example of using `enable_if` in defaulted template arguments to control the overload set.)

Comment: You're a life savior :) I'm new to these "template programming" tricks, I think that's exactly what I need. Let me test it and I'll validate the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could write an SFINAE-friendly `common_type` -- I'm personally in the camp that traits should almost always SFINAE. To wit:

```
// Black hole metafunction that eats everything
template<typename...> struct void_ { using type = void; };

template<typename... T>
using Void = typename void_<T...>::type;

// Due to std::common_type being variadic we need to
// pass a variadic pack around
template<typename... T> struct list {};

// Actually defined, but with no member types for SFINAE purposes
template<typename Sequence, typename Sfinae = void>
struct common_type_impl {};

template<typename... T>
struct common_type_impl<list<T...>, Void<typename std::common_type<T...>::type>>
: std::common_type<T...> {};

template<typename... T> struct common_type: common_type_impl<list<T...>> {};
```

Now, when there is no common type between `A<T>` and `U` the overload will be removed from the list of candidates instead of noisily complaining.

It's also possible to replace `std::common_type` entirely as the result it computes has issues of its own, as documented in [DR 2141](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3473.html#2141). I won't outline a replacement because it's not clear what a better solution is, in particular I consider that the proposed resolution of the DR is worse.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly what happens here, because I find it quite tricky actually; when I use this new version of common_type in my code, say once with a defined common-type, and once without, SFINAE is actually going to happen in my own code.. that's your sentence "Now, when there is no..." right? And if there is no common-type at all, for neither of the two implementations, then we are no longer in an SFINAE situation, and it will in that case generate a compile-time error, right (bis)?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I don't follow what you mean by 'once with' -- this is a drop-in replacement of `std::common_type`, and is entirely in terms of it. Wherever you'd use `std::common_type` you use this one instead: it does and means exactly the same, but always results in a soft error rather than a hard error. If this is about explicit specialization then there's nothing special to do -- write the explicit specialization for `std::common_type` and this one will pick them.

Comment: Yes I got what it does. In my case (see original sources) it's not really a template specialization more than a template overload of operator+ ; 'once with' referred to either of the declarations. I just want to make sure your suggestion results in a "mutually exclusive" behavior when calling the operator with valid types, and that passing a type 'B<U>' still results in a "hard error".

Comment: @Sh3ljohn If you want to change or clarify your requirements, edit them in your question. The comments are really too constricted a format for this kind of discussion. Otherwise I'm regularly in the C++ chat.